# JQueryUpdate Multiple Elements from Ajax Response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax request which returns an HTML response.

I would like to replace existing DIVs in the DOM with corresponding IDs with new content.

I believe the approach is something like outlined here:

[Update multiple elements with html from jquery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773529/update-multiple-elements-with-html-from-jquery-ajax-call)

This is my original DOM:

```
<a onclick="ajaxTest();">Test</a>
<div id="x">
 xxx
</div>
<div id="y">
 yyy
</div>
```

This is the response:

```
<div id="response">
    <div id="x" class="room">111</div>
    <div id="y" class="room">222</div>
</div>
```

This is the JS.

```
function ajaxTest(){
    // UPDATE ON SERVER
    $.post("secure/admin/allocateRoom.do", {
        bookingId : 3051,
        roomId : 2291,
        success : function(data) {
            var $response = $(data);
            $response.children().each(function() {
                alert('in');
                $('#' + this.id).html(this.innerHTML);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This now works with the following request:

```
$.post("secure/admin/allocateRoom.do", {
    bookingId : bookingId,
    roomId : roomId
}, function(html) {
    var $response = $(html);
    $response.children().each(function() {
        if (this.id) {
            $('#' + this.id).replaceWith(this);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I just want to clear something up. You say "this is my original DOM," but that is not the DOM. That is a snippet of your HTML code. The DOM is much more complex and isn't really visible on the page, but is very important when writing code on your page. That's a simple way to put it but the DOM is pretty complex when you dig into it.

Comment: And that adds what to the discusssion?

Comment: Knowledge. Why else would you come to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
success : function(data) {
    var $response = $(data);
    $response.children().each(function(){
        if (this.id) {
            $('#'+this.id).replaceWith(this);
        }
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Z87C2/)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and as far I can see it does not appear to enter the loop. I have place an alert in there which doesn't appear.

Comment: The response you posted in your question is not valid HTML. There's a missing quote after `id="response`, and after each `room` div it should be `</div>`, not `<div>`. Once I fixed that, the loop worked in my test.

Comment: Yes, just a typo. I have updated the question with original HTML, response and JS. Nothing happens! If I remove the outer DIV from the response I get an 'invalid XML error' which makes sense so at least something happens client side. Can you post your example?

Comment: See my jsfiddle demo. I've changed my answer to use `replaceWith`, but I don't think that should have made a big difference. This change ensures that the attributes are also copied from the response.

Comment: Yes, your demo works as expected with the same data. Still no success with mine: only difference is that mine comes from a remote source. I have googled 'jquery ajax parse html' and there are quite a few posts. Is any of this discussion relevant?? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529464/parsing-html-string-with-ajax-jquery

Comment: The difference is in $response.children().length which, as expected, results in 2 in your fiddle but is zero in mine.

Comment: I added a check that the element has an ID. If the problem is like the one in the other question, I think this should solve it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. It now works using the request I added to my answer. Missing bracket or something...I don't know. I HATE JAVASCRIPT!